# std::vector weird

Tags: c++, vector, structure

Is it important in which order I put objects to vector? Because right now I have a structure which has some integers, some char array and ID number(unique) and when I try to find that one with specific ID, I can find only that one which I putted as first to vector, but when I put ID of for example second element I get No found but I can still get needed information.
And when I put ID that doesn't exist at all program exit(At least that work).

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Well, it's kind of long code because it's related to simple file system where I can store graphic and information about it in one file.

Comment: still, show at least the code where you do the push to the vector, and where you try to search the item you're looking for. Try to keep it clean, please

Comment: what do you mean by "put", (vector has multiple mutation methods - `push_back`, `insert`, `operator[]` etc.) Also depends on how you are searching, what semantics your structure supports - the question is so vague it's not possible to answer...

Comment: You'll have to clarify your question then. Are you talking about a std::vector<SomeStruct> ? And is your problem related to the ordering of the struct members in SomeStruct? What `find` method are you using?

Comment: Make a testcase. This means abstracting away all the gubbins about graphics and file systems. Just make a new program with dummy data going into a vector that demonstrates what you're doing wrong. :)

Comment: Posted code + it's werid because I made some function that prints all information about this structures and everything is good there (ID also).

Comment: Show the code where you "put" objects to the vector and where you search for them.

Answer (score 1):

The code block

```
else
{
    printf("Trigger could not be found.\n");
}
```

is the problem I think.
If you have IDs 1, 2 and 3 in your vector and search for 2, it will print out "Trigger could not be found the first time round the loop, and then match on the second.

You probably want to return immediately if the file can't be opened, and print out the "Trigger could not be found" after the end of the loop (since if the trigger had been found you would already have returned from the search function)

Comment: Yeah it does excatly as You said.

Comment: Damn man, thanks. I was looking at it since yesterday, now it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I will post it here, the most important parts of code:
Structure:

```
struct Trigger {
    unsigned short int ID;
    char Nazwa_Map_Do_Wczytania[30];
    unsigned Offset_Triggera;
    unsigned x1,y1,x2,y2;
    char Identyfikator[30];
};
```

Code which is suppose to add new trigger to global vector of that structure(damnit == that global vector)

```
    bool UtworzDat(std::vector<std::string> pliki,std::vector<Trigger> trigg, char* sciezka,Naglowek* nagl)
{
Trigger chujew;
    nagl->Ilosc_Triggerow = trigg.size();
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < trigg.size(); i++)
        {
            memset(&chujew,0,sizeof(Trigger));
            chujew.ID = trigg[i].ID;
            strcpy(chujew.Identyfikator,trigg[i].Identyfikator);
            strcpy(chujew.Nazwa_Map_Do_Wczytania,trigg[i].Nazwa_Map_Do_Wczytania);
            chujew.Offset_Triggera = 0;
            chujew.x1 = trigg[i].x1;
            chujew.x2 = trigg[i].x2;
            chujew.y1 = trigg[i].y1;
            chujew.y2 = trigg[i].y2;
            damnit.push_back(chujew);
        }
```

Then I set right offsets:

```
long prawdziwy_offset = 0;
    prawdziwy_offset += sizeof(Naglowek); <--Header of file
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < trigg.size(); i++)
    {
        damnit[i].Offset_Triggera = prawdziwy_offset;
        prawdziwy_offset += sizeof(Trigger);
    }
    prawdziwy_offset += nagl->Ilosc_Obrazow * sizeof(Obraz); <--It's saving structures golding information about each file inside 
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < wszystkie.size(); i++)
    {
        wszystkie[i].Offset_Obrazu = prawdziwy_offset;
        prawdziwy_offset += wszystkie[i].Rozmiar_Obrazu;
    }
```

Then it's being save to .dat file all together with other graphics, then I read header from file and process data. I am sure that saving is good.

Anyway that simple finding:

```
Trigger WyciagnijTriggera(unsigned short int ID, Naglowek* nagl)
{
    Trigger temp;
    memset(&temp,0,sizeof(Trigger));
    FILE* wejscie;
    for (int i = 0; i < damnit.size(); i++)
    {
        if (ID == damnit[i].ID) <--here
        {
            wejscie = fopen(nazwa,"rb"); //<--opening file to find it
            if (wejscie != NULL)
            {
                fseek(wejscie,damnit[i].Offset_Triggera,SEEK_SET); //<--Going to right offset
                fread(&temp,sizeof(Trigger),1,wejscie);
                fclose(wejscie);
                return temp;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Could not open file.\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Trigger could not be found.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

In main it looks like:

```
Naglowek nowy;
    Trigger kut, kutzapis,kutzapis2,kutzapis3;
    memset(&kutzapis,0,sizeof(Trigger));
    memset(&kutzapis2,0,sizeof(Trigger));
    memset(&kutzapis3,0,sizeof(Trigger));
    memset(&kut,0,sizeof(Trigger));
    memset(&nowy,0,sizeof(Naglowek));
    std::vector<Trigger> pedal;
    strcpy(kutzapis.Identyfikator,"pedal");
    strcpy(kutzapis.Nazwa_Map_Do_Wczytania, "tet");
    kutzapis.x1 = 5050;
    kutzapis.x2 = 9090;
    kutzapis.y1 = 2323;
    kutzapis.y2 = 2341;
    kutzapis.ID = 1;
    strcpy(kutzapis2.Identyfikator,"pedal2");
    strcpy(kutzapis2.Nazwa_Map_Do_Wczytania, "tet2");
    kutzapis2.x1 = 50502;
    kutzapis2.x2 = 90902;
    kutzapis2.y1 = 23232;
    kutzapis2.y2 = 23412;
    kutzapis2.ID = 2;
    strcpy(kutzapis3.Identyfikator,"pedal3");
    strcpy(kutzapis3.Nazwa_Map_Do_Wczytania, "tet3");
    kutzapis3.x1 = 505023;
    kutzapis3.x2 = 909023;
    kutzapis3.y1 = 232323;
    kutzapis3.y2 = 234123;
    kutzapis3.ID = 3;
    pedal.push_back(kutzapis3);
    pedal.push_back(kutzapis2);
    pedal.push_back(kutzapis);
    UtworzDat(toto,pedal,"maslo.dat",&nowy); //Creating file
    CzytajDat("maslo.dat",&nowy);
    kut = WyciagnijTriggera(2,&nowy); //Tring to find trigger with ID: 2
    std::cout << kut.ID << std::endl << kut.Identyfikator << std::endl << kut.Nazwa_Map_Do_Wczytania << std::endl << kut.Offset_Triggera << std::endl << kut.x1 << std::endl << kut.x2 << std::endl << kut.y1 << std::endl << kut.y2 << std::endl;
```

Sorry for this long ass code.

Comment: That is absolutely *not* a testcase. Read http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/iso-c++/testcase.xhtml. Also, this should have been an edit to your question, not an answer.